# How to zoom in to a node of a scene that's being displayed in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I have a Scenekit scene in swift UI, I made the scene a UIViewRepresentable, how can I zoom in on one of the nodes of the scene when the user touches that specific node in the Scenekit scene?

```
import SceneKit

struct HouseView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        return SCNView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        let HouseScene = SCNScene(named: "House.scn")
        scnView.scene = HouseScene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = false
        
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        
        scnView.defaultCameraController.maximumVerticalAngle = 10
        scnView.defaultCameraController.minimumVerticalAngle = -10
        scnView.defaultCameraController.maximumHorizontalAngle = 180
        scnView.defaultCameraController.minimumHorizontalAngle = -10
        
        scnView.isJitteringEnabled = true
        
        let CameraNode = HouseScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "CameraNode", recursively: true)
        CameraNode?.position = SCNVector3(x: 12, y:2, z: 0)
    }
}

struct HouseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HouseView()
    }
}`''
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post: 54058938

Create a basic camera class and you can focus on the node touched and set the distance away from it.